# what's the maximum amount of constraints in minizinc

Tags: optimization, constraints, limit, modeling, constraint-programming

I haven't been able to find any reference as to what is the maximum amount of variables and constraints that [minizinc](http://www.minizinc.org/)'s solvers can handle. Specifically I'm interested minizinc's mip solver. I've been getting stack overflow errors on my mac with 8GB when I have about 15k constraints and about 1000 variables. Does anyone know if that's something close to minizinc's real limitations?

Comment: Stackoverflow errors can't be solved by using lots of RAM (such as your 8GB). It's basically code that uses a recursive function (which goes over 1024 calls) which should use a loop instead.

Comment: Thanks for comment, @GeoffreyDeSmet. There is no direct way of writing recursive functions in minizinc, thus it must be related to some internal minizinc's limitation.

Comment: i.e. I must be specifying too many constraints or using too many variables. All of my constraints are just simple loops with summation functions, so no recusion is used whatsoever.

Comment: Try another minizinc implementation (there are several) or look into alternatives ([OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/), Choco, ...)

Comment: I tried the latest version of minizinc and I assume it would be the most reliable one. Do you know if OptPlanner can solve problems of the size I mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like minizinc was crashing due to too many constraints. I was able to model my problem using another open source MIP solver/optimization framework called [SCIP](http://scip.zib.de). I had to learn how to model using mathematical language called [ZIMP](http://zimpl.zib.de).